# re.split code in python

Tags: python, regex

I was going through following code and not sure, how the re.split is splitting the string here.

```
lines = ["surname: Obama, prename: Barack, profession: president", "surname: 
Merkel, prename: Angela, profession: chancellor"]
for line in lines:
    re.split(",* *\w*: ", line)
['', 'Obama', 'Barack', 'president']
['', 'Merkel', 'Angela', 'chancellor']
```

Comment: what's your desired result?

Comment: You have to **ask a question** or your post will be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.split()` is the split() function associated with the Python Regular Expression library (`re`).

In this case, the function is looking for any substrings in the line that match the pattern shown in the `re.split()` function.

The pattern: `",* *\w*: "` breaks out in the following way:

```
",*  > matches zero OR more commas
 *   > matches zero OR more spaces
\w*  > matches zero OR more word characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z, _)
: "  > matches a colon followed by a space
```

Basically, it tries to find: things like:

`surname:`

`, prename:`

`, profession:`

Where these patterns are found, they are stripped out of the line, leaving behind the values shown in the list. The empty string `''` found in the first position in the list is because the `split()` function includes an empty string IF the split pattern is the first OR last element in the string.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what

```
re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)
```

is doing here, let's have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.split):

> Split *string* by the occurrences of *pattern*.

So from your example, you are looking for all `",* *\w*: "` in your text and use them as delimiters between your desired resulting text.

The pattern you are using is looking for any number of `,` followed by any number of whitespaces, any number of word-characters followed by `:` and a whitespace.

For your example this would mean:
`surname: Obama , prename: Barack , profession: president`
(italic: delimiter, which gets removed, bold: resulting parts of the list). As you see, there is a match directly at the beginning of the string, thus splitting away an empty string `''`, followed by the three entries after the `:`. That's exactly what your result lists say.